# CopyFile function only works on xp

Tags: file, delphi, operating-system, delphi-xe2

I have a delphi form with a button on it. At the click of this button, it allows user to browse for a file and copy the file to a directory.

My code for the function is this:

```
function TdmData.CopyAFile(Const Sourcefile, DestFile: string): boolean;
var Src, Dest : PChar;
begin
  Src := StrAlloc(Length(SourceFile)+1);
  Dest := StrAlloc(Length(DestFile)+1);
try
  StrPCopy(Src,SourceFile);
  StrPCopy(Dest,DestFile);
  result := (CopyFile(Src,Dest,FALSE));
finally
  StrDispose(Src);
  StrDispose(Dest);
end;
end;
```

The click event for the button:

```
CopyAFile(fn, Path +'\'+ ExtractFileName(fn));
```

What I cant understand when I run this form and press the button on a win XP machine, it works fine, if I browse to the directory to where it is being copied to I can see the file in there.

However running this form on a later OS such as Win 8.1 it does not copy the file, again checking the directory I see no file in there.

I don't get any errors, I've stepped through the code which goes through fine.

Has anyone ever come across this or have an idea what the cause could be? If so any help would be great.

Comment: Do you have permission to write to the target directory?

Comment: Are you copying to the program files directory or any other system directory? Maybe your file is copied to the virtual store.

Comment: I have checked permissions, can't see any issues there. I have tried multiple directories and still no luck

Comment: @Dag Do you use `WinAPI.Windows.CopyFile` ir is your `CopyFile` method self defned?

Comment: @Wosi WinAPI.Windows.CopyFile

Comment: `CopyFile` works correctly on all versions of Windows. Your problem is that you don't have write permission on the target directory. Because of UAC.  Which was introduced 10 years ago. "I don't get any errors". You aren't checking for errors so how can you know that there are no errors. Please read the documentation of `CopyFile`. It will be failing and `GetLastError` will return `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. Or perhaps your app is virtualized and `CopyFile` succeeds but writes to the virtual store.

Comment: *have an idea what the cause could be?* Yes. A developer who hasn't stayed current with OS changes over the past 10 years.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not doing any error checking.
If the [`CopyFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information call [`GetLastError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (or raise an exception via `RaiseLastOSError`)

e.g.

```
if not CopyFile(A, B, False) then
  RaiseLastOSError;
```

or equivalently

```
Win32Check(CopyFile(A, B, False));
```

BTW, correct usage is:

```
CopyFile(PChar(Sourcefile) , PChar(Destfile), False);
```

No need for the extra allocations.

---

If you do not include a UAC manifest, then your application is running in [virtualized mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/927387). And saving files to restricted areas e.g. `Program Files` will not raise any errors but actually save the file into a virtual store location e.g. `[CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA]\VirtualStore\Program Files`.

Comment: using Win32Check I get system error Code 2 The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: @Dag, That answers your *"have an idea what the cause could be?"* The file name you provided does not exist.

Comment: if the file does not exist then surely I wouldn't be able to see it when i browse and select it?

Comment: The system is right. The file doesn't exist. Presumably file system redirector. You copy file from system32 but that's redirected to syswow64. If only you'd shown an mcve.